# How do I only require LDAP login once?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, ldap

I'm protecting a few different directories with LDAP. My problem is that you have to log into each directory separately even though it's the same user for almost all of them. Here's the pertinent part of my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

<Directory /var/www/wiki>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require user galapagos
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/staging>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require user galapagos
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mantis>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require user galapagos
</Directory>

<Directory /home/jason/projects>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require user jason
</Directory>
```

How do I factor out all the parts that are the same and only require galapagos' login once?

Comment: Having the same AuthName *should* tell the client to reuse its cached userid/password.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox on Windows.

Comment: Hmm...where does LDAP enter into the picture? Looks like basic auth with password files.

Comment: Okay, whatever. How do I make the login prompt appear only once instead of once per directory?

Comment: The wiki, staging and mantis folders wouldn't happen to be on different virtual hosts would they?  In that case the browser will not use the cached login as realm is host specific.  In order to get around this you would need to use some sort of single-sign-in feature.

Comment: Yes, they are on different virtual hosts. Now it's so much clearer. Thank you for explaining how that works. Any suggestions how how to implement a single sign-on feature?

Comment: Sorry.  You just tapped out my "expertise". ;-)  Suggest you make that a new question and someone will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no great answers here, my answer was to buy the book *LDAP System Administration*.

Comment: Huh, I've never seen anybody actually RTFM themself!

Comment: You may want to look at an Apache book (maybe the Apache Cookbook) would be of more help to you.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried to do?  Your conf file appears to use local (to the server) accounts, not LDAP accounts.

Searching for ["apache with ldap authentication" on your favorite search engine](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=LDAP+System+Administration#hl=en&expIds=17259,26637,26653,26794,27045,27101,27103,27182,27283,27294&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=apache+with+ldap+authentication&cp=13&qe=YXBhY2hlIHdpdGggbA&qesig=cXcwJyderne6GRQlVV_YdQ&pkc=AFgZ2tmpRWLkx9z5zXFJph-wBYls6pEhPdeUuxHqGyipFEkTsJAcJLiOTfgx_4dST4ALt0t4ugntkoyvS5b7-NWIBxxW_LgaBQ&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=apache+with+l&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7f24c5256a086621) should get you some reasonable results.  (I'd recommend that you specify the flavor of LDAP that you're using, especially if it's Active Directory.)  I see:

- [mod-auth_ldap from Apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_ldap.html)
- [Linux Tutorial - Apache Web Login Authentication from yolinux.com](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html)
- ...and so on...

Further, it actually looks like you actually want to learn how to make a session persistent and/or cache credentials.  Try searching using those terms.

Answer (score -1):

If the directories are on different virtual hosts you will have to use NTLM authentication to get SSO functionality.

Comment: Is that a Windows thing? I'm on Linux.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but both FF and Apache support NTLM authentication, no mater the platform. You could try setting up Kerberos for real SSO, but it is much more complicated.